# I keep getting a syntax error in my for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, syntax

I'm not sure what's wrong with the subset of this loop, but I keep getting a Syntax error:

```
for (i in 1:length(wc_comp$Section)) {
  print(ggplot(data = (subset(wc_comp, Section == [i]))) +
          geom_jitter(aes(x = Headline, y = Word.Count, color=cols), size=5, width = 0.05) +
          stat_summary(aes(x = Headline, y = Word.Count, group = Article[i]),
                       fun = median, fun.min = median, fun.max = median,
                       geom = "crossbar", color = "black", width = 0.7, lwd = 0.2) +
          ylim(min(wc_comp$Word.Count), max(wc_comp$Word.Count)) +
          xlab("Story") +
          ylab ("Word Count") +
          ggtitle([i]) +
          theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", size = 10),
                text = element_text(family = "System Font"),axis.text.x = element_text(size=6)) +
          scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)))
}
```

Comment: Please include the error itself, there are too many to guess.

Comment: Several things jump out, though: (1) `[i]` is not valid R code, use `i` to refer to the value of `i`; (2) `i` is in this case always an integer, and it is a logical error to try to compare `Section` to `i`. If you get a match, I am 99% confident that it is a bad match. Perhaps you mean `Section == Section[i]`? (3) I'm done theorizing, without sample data I don't want to come up with hypothetical fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the syntax `[i]` in two places to refer to the looping variable `i`, which is causing the syntax error. Removing the `[ ]` on lines 2 and 10 resolves the issue:

```
for (i in 1:length(wc_comp$Section)) {
  print(ggplot(data = (subset(wc_comp, Section == i))) +
          geom_jitter(aes(x = Headline, y = Word.Count, color=cols), size=5, width = 0.05) +
          stat_summary(aes(x = Headline, y = Word.Count, group = Article[i]),
                       fun = median, fun.min = median, fun.max = median,
                       geom = "crossbar", color = "black", width = 0.7, lwd = 0.2) +
          ylim(min(wc_comp$Word.Count), max(wc_comp$Word.Count)) +
          xlab("Story") +
          ylab ("Word Count") +
          ggtitle(i) +
          theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", size = 10),
                text = element_text(family = "System Font"),axis.text.x = element_text(size=6)) +
          scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 10)))
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but realize that `Section == i` is a logical error even if it is not a syntax error. Imagine `for (i in 1:length(mtcars$disp)) mtcars[mtcars$disp == i,]` ... will never match.

Comment: Fair point, but also consider that we don't know what values `wc_comp$Section` take on. If the condition `wc_comp$Section[n] == n` holds, then I think the logical error disappears.

Comment: The *only* time that that will work is if `wc_comp$Section` is class `integer`, and perfectly increasing by `1` from `1` over its length. If anything is not the same, then the OP's code is logically inconsistent. If it is the same, though, I argue that this code is still fragile and far too easily will go astray. Either one iterates on *indices* using `for (i in 1:length(.))` (which is bad anyway, should use `seq_len`), or one iterates on *values* with `for (i in wc_comp$Section)`. If they happen to coincide once, congrats, it's still bad and fragile.